# substring of the first 4 characters from a textField in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, string, swift4

I'm trying to create a substring of the first 4 characters entered in a textField in Swift 4 on my iOS app.

Since the change to Swift 4 I'm struggling with basic String parsing.

So based on Apple documentation I'm assuming I need to use the substring.index function and I understand the second parameter (offsetBy) is the number of characters to create a substring with.  I'm just unsure how I tell Swift to start at the beginning of the string.

This is the code so far:

```
  let postcode = textFieldPostcode.text

  let newPostcode = postcode?.index(STARTATTHEBEGININGOFTHESTRING, offsetBy: 4)
```

I hope my explanation makes sense, happy to answer any questions on this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In Swift 4 you can use

```
let string = "Hello World"
let first4 = string.prefix(4) // Hell
```

The type of the result is a new type `Substring` which behaves very similar to `String`. However if `first4` is supposed to leave the current scope – for example as a return value of a function – it's recommended to create a `String` explicitly:

```
let first4 = String(string.prefix(4)) // Hell
```

See also [SE 0163 String Revision 1](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0163-string-revision-1.md)

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4:

```
let postcode = textFieldPostcode.text!
let index = postcode.index(postcode.startIndex, offsetBy: 4)
let newPostCode = String(postcode[..<index])
```